# Output to a file using file descriptor

Tags: linux, redirection, file-descriptors

I was wondering if it's possible to redirect output of one process (in OS X/ Linux) to another process if I know the fd of another process. For example:

I open a file using vim: `vim /tmp/test`. This opens a file and when I use `lsof | grep test` to find out the file descriptor I get:

```
vim    18689 user    4u     REG     1,2     12288 2675530 /private/tmp/.test.swp
```

It tells me that FD is 4 and that it's open for writing and reading.

Is there a way I can now redirect output of another process to that file descriptor (eg. echo 'test' >&4 - this doesn't work but you get the idea)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each process has it's own FD - table (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor ), otherwise process A would have to communicate with process B about the filedescriptors (and not only with B but also with all the other processes on the machine). So, just knowing the (internal) FD is not enough, you need to know where this FD points to:

```
$> ls /proc/2964/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 3 -> [eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 4 -> socket:[1116342098]
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 5 -> /home/user/.irssi/logs/freenode/#channel.2014-10.log
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  6 15:09 6 -> [eventfd]
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 Okt  7 19:09 9 -> /home/user/.irssi/away.log
```

As you can see, there are some FD open in the irc-client I use (irssi), stdin is read from the file `/dev/pts/1`. Given that I have the permissions to write to that file I am able to pipe stuff into that file:

```
$> echo "/names" >> /dev/pts/1
```

And at least something will happen. So, you can redirect output of one program into another allthough that might lead to strange issues.